# Count of files in each sub-directories

Tags: linux, bash

I would like a BASH command to list just the count of files in each subdirectory of a directory.

E.g.  in directory `/tmp` there are `dir1`, `dir2`, ...  I'd like to see :

```
`dir1` : x files 
`dir2` : x files ...
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Assuming you want a recursive count of files only, not directories and other types, something like this should work:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d | while read dir; do
  printf "%-25.25s : " "$dir"
  find "$dir" -type f | wc -l
done
```

Comment: Also, I get "find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a non-option argument -type, but options are not positional (-maxdepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments."

Comment: Both answers given so far will give incorrect results in the unlikely case that there are files whose names include newline characters.  You can handle that with a `find` ... `-print0 | xargs -0` ....

Comment: @jldupont: move the depth arguments before the ´-type d´, I've edited the answer.

Comment: Yes, and let me add the information that this excellent solution will not take any *external* variables and thus will work with `bash` `alias`!!

Comment: fast, and piping `sort -rn -k 2,2 -t$':'` you get the DESC list

Comment: Any time you want to use `read foo`, consider [`IFS= read -r foo`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/209123/108618). In many cases the latter is what you really want. This is such case. The improvement does not solve the (already noted) problem with possible newline characters in pathnames.

Answer (score 20):

This task fascinated me so much that I wanted to figure out a solution myself.
It doesn't even take a while loop and *MAY* be faster in execution speed.
Needless to say, Thor's efforts helped me a lot to understand things in detail.

So here's mine:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c 'echo "{} : $(find "{}" -type f | wc -l)" file\(s\)' \;
```

It looks modest for a reason, for it's way more powerful than it looks. :-)

However, should you intend to include this into your `.bash_aliases` file, it must look like this:

```
alias somealias='find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c '\''echo "{} : $(find "{}" -type f | wc -l)" file\(s\)'\'' \;'
```

Note the very tricky handling of nested *single* quotes. And no, it is **not** possible to use double quotes for the `sh -c` argument.

Comment: It is slower as it invokes /bin/sh for each directory. You can check this with `strace -fc script`. Your version makes about 70% more system-calls. +1 for shorter code :-)

Comment: inspired by this; sorted by filecount: `find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -exec sh -c 'echo "$(find "{}" -type f | wc -l)" {}' \; | sort -nr`

Comment: [Never embed `{}` in the shell code](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/156010/108618).

Answer (score 15):

```
find . -type f | cut -d"/" -f2 | uniq -c
```

Lists a folders and files in the current folder with a count of files found beneath.  Quick and useful IMO. (files show with count 1).

Comment: How about a little explanation of how it is working ? :)

Comment: awesome, thanks! You might want to add `| sort -rn` to sort subdirs by number of files.

Comment: Works well except also shows files in the current dir, not just subdirs...

Answer (score 2):

Using find is definitely the way to go if you want to count recursively, but if you just want a count of the files directly under a certain directory:

`ls dir1 | wc -l`

Comment: I don't want to do this for each of the 1000's of directories I've got there...

Comment: Then use xargs. `ls -d */ | xargs -n1 ls | wc -l` (Use the answer you accepted if it already works, though! This is just And Now You Know.)

Comment: your proposal didn't show up any results in many seconds whereas the answer I accepted did.

Comment: @jrajav this approach absolutely fails for directories with whitespace in them. This is why `find` is so important. (let alone `-print0` and `xargs -0`, already pointed out by Scott in the other answer)

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} sh -c 'printf "%4d : %s\n" "$(find {} -type f | wc -l)" "{}"'
```

I need often need to count the number of files in my sub-directories and use this command.  I prefer the count to appear first.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this python code. Boot up the interpreter by running `python3` and paste this:

```
folder_path = '.'
import os, glob
for folder in sorted(glob.glob('{}/*'.format(folder_path))):
    print('{:}: {:>8,}'.format(os.path.split(folder)[-1], len(glob.glob('{}/*'.format(folder)))))
```

Or a recursive version for nested counts:

```
import os, glob
def nested_count(folder_path, level=0):
    for folder in sorted(glob.glob('{}/'.format(os.path.join(folder_path, '*')))):
        print('{:}{:}: {:,}'.format('    '*level, os.path.split(os.path.split(folder)[-2])[-1], len(glob.glob(os.path.join(folder, '*')))))
        nested_count(folder, level+1)
nested_count('.')
```

Example output:

```
>>> figures: 5
>>> misc: 1
>>> notebooks: 5
>>>     archive: 65
>>>     html: 12
>>>     py: 12
>>>     src: 14
>>> reports: 1
>>>     content: 6
>>> src: 1
>>>     html_download: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

For reliable methods of counting files in a directory, see this answer of mine: [*What is a reliable code to count files?*](https://superuser.com/a/1687310/432690)

In your case we additionally need to iterate over subdirectories. A `for` loop is good for this:

```
for d in */; do
    c="$(cd -- "$d" && find . ! -name . -exec printf a \; | wc -c)"
    if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; then c="?"; fi
    printf '%-25s : %s\n' "${d%/}" "$c"
done
```

Notes:

- Normally `*/` does not match directories with names starting with a dot ("hidden" directories). In Bash `shopt -s dotglob` changes this.
- `! -name .` is responsible for not counting the respective subdirectory itself.
- `${d%/}` [removes trailing `/`](https://superuser.com/a/1649184/432690). If we used `*` instead of `*/` in the `for` loop, then there would be nothing to remove, but the loop would iterate over non-directories as well.
- [Double dash (`--`)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/11382/108618) is useful in case a name starts with `-`. If we used `./*/` in the `for` loop, then there would be no need for `--`, but you probably would want to remove the leading `./` while printing the output, this would complicate the code.
- In the output `?` appears in case of a problem. Failing `cd` (probably because of insufficient permissions) is the problem I had in mind. `find` unable to descend to some (sub-…)subdirectory does not qualify as a problem in this context. If you see a number then it means `find` found as many files there, so there are at least as many files in the directory. If you see `?` then it means `find` most likely didn't run because `cd` had failed.
- See the [already linked answer](https://superuser.com/a/1687310/432690), it will help you tailor the `find` command to your needs (e.g. non-recursive solution, counting files of a specific type, some optimizations).
- Multi-byte characters in names will confuse `printf` and the output may appear misaligned.
- The format that prints names is `%-25s`, so any name is printed as-is (plus padding). Newline characters, carriage return characters, escape sequences in names may cause results you don't expect. With `printf` builtin in Bash use `%q` instead of `%s` (it will be `%-25q` in our case) to mitigate the problem.

Answer (score -1):

What I use... This makes an array of all the subdirectories in the one you give as a parameter. Print the subdirectory and the count of that same subdirectory until all the subdirectories are processed.

```
#!/bin/bash    
directories=($(/bin/ls -l $1 | /bin/grep "^d" | /usr/bin/awk -F" " '{print $9}'))

for item in ${directories[*]}
    do
        if [ -d "$1$item" ]; then
            echo "$1$item"
            /bin/ls $1$item | /usr/bin/wc -l
        fi
    done
```

Comment: -1. [Do not parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Your code still falls into the [Bash pitfall number one](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29); the fact you used an array only obfuscates the problem, bad things may happen when you define the array. Worse, *additional* bad things may happen when you use `${directories[*]}` (it should be `"${directories[@]}"`).

Answer (score -1):

Output as csv format for Folders :

```
for f in $(find * -type d); do echo $f,$(ls ./$f | wc -l) ; done
```

output:

```
aFolder,30

bFolder,20

cFolder,10
```

Comment: Why did you post an answer very similar to [your other answer](https://superuser.com/a/1690776/432690) and with *the same set of flaws*?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).