# Correct regex doesn't work in bash

Tags: bash, regex

My problem might be solvable in other ways, but I can't help but wonder why it doesn't work using regex.

The code

```
#!/bin/bash
python_version=$(python3 --version)
regexp='(?<=^Python )3\.[0-9]+'
[[ $python_version =~ $regexp ]]
echo $BASH_REMATCH
```

should yield `3.8` for `python` version `3.8.10`, for example. And it does, when I check it at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com). But when I stick it in the `bash`, it does nothing.

I should note, that `$python_version` equals to `Python 3.8.10` in this test case.

I would really like to know, how to solve this particular problem using `bash` only.

I'm using `Ubuntu 20.04`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Positive lookbehind (`(?<=…)`) does not work in POSIX ERE used by `[[ … =~ … ]]`.

In your use case you can match a broader pattern and remove the excessive part later:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
python_version=$(python3 --version)
regexp='^Python 3\.[0-9]+'
[[ $python_version =~ $regexp ]]
echo "${BASH_REMATCH#Python }"
```

Note this approach wouldn't work for arbitrary regex instead of your `^Python` . In `${var#pattern}` the pattern is like filename generation pattern, *not a regex*. See [this another answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1649184/432690).

Comment: I'm able to successfully use it, thank you, but I don't understand, what the `${BASH_REMATCH#Python }` piece does. Could you, please, explain?

Comment: @winwin Have you seen the linked answer and the example there? `${parameter#[word]}`, Remove Smallest Prefix Pattern. Or are you asking about `$BASH_REMATCH` you used first and I followed?