# Set variable in Bash file by extracting text from another file

Tags: macos, command-line, bash

I am on macOS.

Here is my source file:

```
#!/bin/bash

version=42

o_ver=$version
let "version+=1"
echo Compiling version $version up from $o_ver

# . . . many more lines
```

I want to extract the version number (`42` in this case) and use it to set the `r_ver` variable in the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

r_ver= ??
```

I tried using grep but most examples use the `-P` flag not available on macOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command extracts lines from `sourcefile` that start with `version=` (possibly indented):

```
<sourcefile grep '^[[:blank:]]*version='
```

To get the first line only, pipe to `head -n 1` (important if there may be more matching lines):

```
<sourcefile grep '^[[:blank:]]*version=' | head -n 1
```

Your new script should assign the output of the above command to a variable. The variable will hold like `version=42`. Then you need to [get rid of `version=`](https://superuser.com/a/1649184/432690). Final snippet:

```sh
r_ver="$(<sourcefile grep '^[[:blank:]]*version=' | head -n 1)"
r_ver="${r_ver#*version=}"
```

AFAIK everything I used here is portable.