# How to extract a particular part from a string in bash

Tags: bash, string

There is this output i get:

```
Duration: 00:03:27.05, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 336 kb/s
```

I want to extract `00:03:27.05` from this whole string(Values Can Change).

So far I have tried:

```
String="Duration: 00:03:27.05, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 336 kb/s"

String="${String#*:}"
String="${String%,*,*}"
echo $String
```

It gives the desired results, but here I have to Declare `String` variable Two times and have to cut specific part of string separately.

So I Just want to Know an easiest and Straight-Forward approach to do it.

Thanks in Advance for Help :)

Comment: Have you tried a regex based approach?

Comment: Is it always in the same format of "Duration: NN:NN:NN.NN, Start: "... ?

Comment: This is the Right Way because the shell does it (no extra process(es) needed). But (1) [quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618), even while `echo`ing. (2) `String="${String%%,*}"` may be better (see the citation [here](https://superuser.com/a/1649184/432690)).

Comment: yes! The Format remains the Same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like with `awk`:

```
awk -F'[ ,]' '{print $2}' input_file
```

Example:

```
echo "Duration: 00:03:27.05, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 336 kb/s"|awk -F'[ ,]' '{print $2}'
00:03:27.05
```

Comment: As Kamil Maciorowski noted, it's theoretically faster to do the processing inside the shell. But using awk is much clearer and easier to understand -- and change if needed. Bending over backwards to be fractionally faster is false economy here. If you really need that performance boost, don't do this in an interpreted scripting language at all.

Comment: @mpez0, `awk` will show full speed on more complex operations, this is just read, separate and print. And for me do not worth the effort to write it in `C` for example :)

Comment: I'm trying to agree with your post and show that the convoluted do-it-all-in-bash isn't worth the hassle. That's why I upvoted it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that this specific time pattern is the only one in your string, a very straightforward approach would be to simply use grep with the -P flag that allows us to interpret patterns as Perl-compatible regular expressions :

```bash
String="Duration: 00:03:27.05, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 336 kb/s"

echo $String | grep -oP "[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}"
```

This would output `00:03:27.05`

Answer (score 0):

Bash lets you use POSIX ERE regular expressions:

```
String="Duration: 00:03:27.05, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 336 kb/s"

if [[ $String =~ Duration:\ ([^,]+), ]]; then
    String=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
fi
```

In plain Bourne shell, `/bin/expr` is the standard tool:

```
expr "$String" : 'Duration: \([^,]*\),'
```

(Note that expr uses BRE regex syntax instead of ERE, so grouping uses `\( \)` and the `+` operator is unavailable. Also, expr's regex is implicitly anchored to the beginning of the string, whereas `=~` searches anywhere within the string.)